# try catch around mixed content warning

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a way that I can try catch around a Mixed Content Warning using Javascript?  I get this warning whenever I call a loading gif using IE 8 in compatibility mode.  I know what the problem is, so I figure I can just try catch around the mixed content warning.  Anybody know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is no JavaScript error, but a browser warning, you can't use `try/catch` here.

Comment: any links or requests must use https instead of http, to get rid of this error